# Exclusão de dados via Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

No banco de dados utilizado pela minha aplicação tenho uma tabela que eu defini como temporária que gravo alguns dados porém ao final do processo não necessito mais da informações registradas naquela tabela, como devo fazer esta tabela ser limpa seria mais útil realizar um processo via banco de dados ou a aplicação mesmo deva se encarregar disto.?

Utilizo o `Hibernate` e tentei algumas situações porém eu consigo fazer o `em.remove(temp);` a partir de um objeto definido, e não de todo o conteúdo.

Um exemplo de como eu faço uma pesquisa no banco:

```
 public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return ConexaoJPA.getEntityManager();
}

public List find(int id) {

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {

        Query q = em.createQuery("from Temp where cod=" + id + "");

        return (List<Temp>) q.getResultList();

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: E aí, conseguiu? Se sim, considere incluir sua solução, pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: não consegui, estou verificando a documentação do Hibernate pra ver se consigo algo mais preciso.

Comment: O que acontece com as sugestões abaixo, algu merro? Consegue debugar e ver o que está acontecendo, ou fornecer um exemplo reproduzível do que está fazendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer usar o `remove`, pode usar algo assim:

```
Temp temp = new Temp();
temp.setId(1);
getEntityManager().remove(temp);
```

Neste caso o objeto deve estar na sessão, caso contrário será levantada uma `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity`, algo assim, não lembro ao certo agora :)

Usando JPQL você pode usar algo assim:

```
getEntityManager()
    .createQuery("delete from Temp t where t.id = :id")
    .setParameter("id", id)
    .executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
public int truncate(String nomeTabela){
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery('truncate table ' + nomeTabela);
    return query.executeUpdate();
}
```

`

Comment: Vou atualizar a pergunta para especificar melhor como eu uso hoje. Pois eu não session e sim Entity  Manager.

Comment: Já tentou: Query query = manager.createNativeQuery()?

Comment: já tentei mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Estranho não  funcionar. Veja este post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041547/truncate-table-in-play-framework-jpa-hibernate

Answer (score 1):

```
@Resource
UserTransaction utc;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "xyz")
EntityManager em;

try {
    utx.begin();

    Query q1 = em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM tabela");

    q1.executeUpdate();

    utc.commit();
} catch (NotSupportedException | SystemException | SecurityException | IllegalStateException | RollbackException | HeuristicMixedException | HeuristicRollbackException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: também sem sucesso sua opção.

Comment: Lança algum erro? você está abrindo uma transação antes de fazer o delete?

Comment: não lança nenhum erro.

Comment: e a transação? posta o que você tentou utilizando `em.createNativeQuery`

Answer (score -1):

Sei que é antigo esse post, mas acho que posso ajudar. Segue um exemplo de como fazer o delete:

```
@Stateful
@Local (EmpresaLocal.class)
@Remote (EmpresaRemote.class)
@RemoteBinding( jndiBinding="EmpresaBean/remote" )
@LocalBinding( jndiBinding="EmpresaBean/local" )
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class EmpresaBean  { 
    private List<Empresa> empresas; 
    
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="Curriculo")  
    private EntityManagerFactory emf=null;
    
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Curriculo")  
    private EntityManager entitymanager= null;   
     
    private UserTransaction transaction = null;
        
    public EmpresaBean() { 
        empresas = new ArrayList<Empresa>();   
        this.emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Curriculo");
        this.entitymanager=emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            this.transaction = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup("UserTransaction");
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 

 public void remove(Empresa empresa) {
        try {
            transaction.begin();            
            entitymanager.remove(entitymanager.merge(empresa));
            entitymanager.flush();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            try {
                transaction.rollback();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SystemException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
    }
}
```